# Android, How to show array of address of images with intent?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, navigation

I have an array which includes URL address of for example 20 images. When user clicks on a button i need to show image in full screen mode and if user touched the screen and his finger points to right or left then show next or previous image (something like loading image from gallery and navigating to right or left).

Is it possible to do it with intents? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it, find out the Gallery example in [Android Universal Image loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader).

Comment: Thanks dear Paresh, I think this is useful when we have a single image. Can we use it within grid or list inflater (adapter)?